# After ARC, in what ways you can still refer to a deallocated object by mistake?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is it still possible? I mean weak pointers are automatically nulled. Strong pointers only deallocate when pointed somewhere else.

Can we still have an error of pointing to deallocated objects?

__unsafe_unretained is done by those that knows what they're doing. So it's not really by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

__unsafe_unretained, CFTypeRefs, malloc()ed memory

Comment: dispatch_queue_t for system lower than iOS 6.

Comment: Or, equivalently, before Mac OSX 10.8

Comment: Good. I am thinking of by mistakes. If you do __unsafe_unretained you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 13):

Beware of __autoreleasing vs @autoreleasepool. The compiler isn't smart enough to retain the __autoreleasing variable's value when it drains the autorelease pool. This includes @autoreleasepool inside a method with an NSError** parameter.

Beware of __block __autoreleasing variables. This includes a block object that sets an NSError** variable. Some block-based API wraps the block call in an autorelease pool, so you end up with the same flaw as above.

Beware of API that is effectively unsafe-unretained. For example, many delegate pointers in AppKit and UIKit are unsafe-unretained, not zeroing-weak. If you arrange your object graph incorrectly then you'll crash when the delegate object is deallocated and the kit tries to use it.

Beware of heap-allocated C arrays of object pointers. It is possible to do it correctly, but if you're not careful then you get leaks or crashes.

Beware of thread races. If you have a multithreading bug then all bets are off.